# LinqToExcel:Is there a similar function like Range.find() which is used for searching the cell value?

Tags: c#, excel, linq-to-excel

I read the [doc](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel) and couldn't find a method like [Range.find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)  in LinqToExcel.

I want to get  the position of the specific value,such as the row and column number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried MATCH() with ROW() and COLUMN() ? These are excel functions as you tagged excel...

Comment: Then don't tag excel...

Comment: MATCH() with ROW() and COLUMN()?How to use?

Comment: I deal with .xlsx and .csv format file so I tagged excel....